# Uncaught Exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in JMETER 2.9 with third party websocket plugin

Tags: java, websocket, jmeter, classnotfoundexception, jmeter-plugins

I have created one new jar namely `ApacheJMeter_WebSocket.jar`.

Then I placed it in `/apache-jmeter-2.9/lib/ext/` folder.

When i start the jmeter from bin i observe this error and not able to proceed further:

```
Uncaught Exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError. See log file for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class   org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory. See log file for details.
```

I tried removing duplicate entries in pom.xml (in jar attached here with) and updated all the dependent jars with the latest version.

Can any one throw some light on this, which will be more useful.

Actually ApacheJMeter_WebSocket.jar direct download is not available, so i just collected the source from git hub and cleaned all the errors with the required libraries.

So if some can help with this issue, it will be very useful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16153951/993246

Comment: what does the log file say?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

- Your plugin is missing dependency jars that should be put in lib folder
- Your plugin is incompatible with your JMeter version

Anyway, as of September 2018, the best options for load testing Websocket is using this 3rd party plugin by Peter Doornbosh:

- https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers

You can install this plugin using JMeter Plugins Manager:

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/