# WebSocket plugin for Jmeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Can someone share me a link with plugin sampler for Websocket protocol for JMeter?

I tried to install from the link below: https://github.com/kawasima/mod_proxy_websocket.
But not sure how to get that.

I am new to the tool.
Thanks and appreciated.

Answer (score 21):

Link in your question looks to be not for jmeter plugin but for proxying module for Apache http server.
Correct link seems to be https://github.com/kawasima/jmeter-websocket - jmeter plugin for WebSocket protocol.

To use it you have to:

- download project sources;
- build ApacheJMeter_WebSocket.jar using maven;
- place jar into `$JMETER_HOME/lib/ext/` dir.

---

Jar files successfully built from sources using maven 3.0 (`mvn validate compile package`):

- [ApacheJmeter_websocket-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89045969/jmeter/ApacheJmeter_websocket-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar)
- [ApacheJmeter_websocket-dist-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89045969/jmeter/ApacheJmeter_websocket-dist-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) - with dependencies.

WebSocket Sampler available in the list of Samplers:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is another WebSocket plugin for JMeter. It supports the RFC6455 (v13) of the WebSocket protocol.

Link: https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter

Features:

- Supports HTTS/HTTPS (ws/wss) version of the WebSocket protocol
- Option to ignore SSL certificate errors
- Streaming allows for a single connection to remain open for the duration of the test
- Response has to match predefined regular expression
- Response timeout
- Response message backlog (build the Sampler response from multiple server messages)
- Connection could be closed if server sends a message matching predefined regular expression

Comment: Could you please add Ant/Maven/Ivy/whatever build system configuration so the one could build a jar from sources?

Comment: I know I will have to do this at some point when I get some time.

There is already build JAR under Releases which you can download and put into JMeter lib/ext folder. You will also need dependencies as per Wiki page.

Comment: Maciej: your jar file didn't seem to work for me, can you help?

Comment: I'm receiving following on attempt to use your plugin:

 - Unexpected error: null
JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.ServiceSocket.sendMessage(ServiceSocket.java:131)
JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.WebSocketSampler.sample(WebSocketSampler.java:102)
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: I suspect that there was either a connection problem (incorrect host name) or a race condition.

In either case the problem should now be fixed and additional messages should shed more light on the problem. I will shortly release update on GitHub

The sampler will show diagnostic messages when opened in the Results tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot Maciej, version 1.0.1 works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another (fairly new) JMeter WebSocket plugin:
https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers.

See the readme for current features; it's still in active development.

Answer (score 2):

I can`t comment previous post. But this plugin has one problem with concurency when running a large quantity of threads. I got this error:

```
[Problems]
 - Unexpected error: null
java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(LinkedList.java:953)
java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:886)
JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.ServiceSocket.getResponseMessage(ServiceSocket.java:125)
JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.WebSocketSampler.sample(WebSocketSampler.java:156)
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

So I just replaced one line in the ServiceSocket.java:

```
protected Deque<String> responeBacklog = new LinkedList<String>();
```

with this line:

```
Queue<String> responeBacklog = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();
```

It solved my problem :)

Comment: Where is that file located?

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Jmeter you dont need to spend a lot of time learning the Jmeter UI and function to do the websocket load testing. We have a dedicated tool now to do load testing on websockets. It is named as [Thor](https://github.com/observing/thor).

Thanks to the developers for making it simple, light weight and opensource.

Comment: Thor has a problem of closing the websocket conenction and not able to keep it idle. Loadtesting is difficult to acheive.