# How to get websocket-plugin working in Jmeter?

Tags: websocket, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have to carry out few tests using Web-socket via Jmeter, i found the jar files (`ApacheJmeter_websocket-dist-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`) in stackoverflow ([WebSocket plugin for Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152648/websocket-plugin-for-jmeter)).

When i send a request to any valid website (eg: echo.websocket.org) then i get `java.net.Protocol Exception: Bad response status 400 Bad Request` or `java.net.Protocol Exception: Bad response status 404 Not Found`.

Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

As per [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) the plugin you've mentioned

> relies on the 8.1.9.v20130131 Jetty libraries version which not fully RFC6455 compliant, but rather a kind of experimental draft. It also doesn't seem to support reusing one TCP session (this is how browsers work and the majority of test cases will be connected with sending lots of messages through one session)

So please consider using newer [WebSocketSampler](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler) instead.